# Supervisor not working on centos7 for laravel-echo-server

Tags: laravel-5.5

Log details are below for the supervisor.log file. Below error comes when I restart the supervisor on cent OS7

> 2018-02-01 17:48:02,392 INFO spawnerr: can't find command
>   '/var/www/laravel/laravel-echo-server' 
> 2018-02-01 17:48:03,393 INFO
>   success: laravel-queue-listener entered RUNNING state, process has
>   stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs) 
> 2018-02-01 17:48:03,394
>   INFO spawnerr: can't find command
>   '/var/www/laravel/laravel-echo-server' 
> 2018-02-01 17:48:05,396 INFO
>   spawnerr: can't find command '/var/www/laravel/laravel-echo-server'
>   
> 2018-02-01 17:48:08,401 INFO spawnerr: can't find command
>   '/var/www/laravel/laravel-echo-server' 
> 2018-02-01 17:48:08,401 INFO
>   gave up: laravel-worker entered FATAL state, too many start retries
>   too quickly

**More about the issue**

I accessed server using putty and ran the command manually `laravel-echo-server start` and everything works but why it does not work if run the same command using supervisor file with below code and restarts supervisor...Here is the screenshot when I try to run the laravel-echo-server manually using putty. But this is of no use when the putty is closed...`laravel-echo-server` gets off also.

[image]

**Command Details for laravel-echo-server are below present in the supervisor file**

```
[program:laravel-worker]
command=/var/www/laravel/laravel-echo-server start
autostart=true
user=root
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/laravel/storage/logs/echoserver.log
```

You can check below that the laravel-echo-server is already installed on the server..

[image]

**Update - 1**

Using command - `which laravel-echo-server`, it is found out that the path of `laravel-echo-server` is `/usr/bin/laravel-echo-server`

When I entered in the above mentioned directory and tried to run the command manually `laravel-echo-server start` , it gave an error Message that laravel-echo-server.json file is missing. I manually added and updated the url(authHost and allowOrigin). Finally, I stopped the command that I ran manually and added the correct path in supervisor file. Now it is like below.

```
[program:echo-server]
command=/usr/bin/laravel-echo-server start
autostart=true
user=root
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/laravel/storage/logs/echoserver.log
```

Then I restarted the supervisor and got the below supervisor logs.

> 2018-02-09 07:19:31,674 INFO success: echo-server entered RUNNING
>   state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
>   
> 2018-02-09 07:19:31,715 INFO exited: echo-server (exit status 0;
>   expected) 
> 2018-02-09 07:19:32,718 INFO spawned: 'echo-server' with pid
>   2286 
> 2018-02-09 07:19:33,648 INFO exited: echo-server (exit status 0;
>   not expected) 
> 2018-02-09 07:19:34,652 INFO spawned: 'echo-server' with
>   pid 2296 
> 2018-02-09 07:19:35,545 INFO exited: echo-server (exit status
>   0; not expected) 
> 2018-02-09 07:19:37,550 INFO spawned: 'echo-server'
>   with pid 2306 
> 2018-02-09 07:19:38,446 INFO exited: echo-server (exit
>   status 0; not expected) 
> 2018-02-09 07:19:41,451 INFO spawned:
>   'echo-server' with pid 2317 
> 2018-02-09 07:19:42,299 INFO exited:
>   echo-server (exit status 0; not expected) 
> 2018-02-09 07:19:43,301 INFO
>   gave up: echo-server entered FATAL state, too many start retries too
>   quickly

I am still facing same 404 error of **socket.io/socket.io.js**

Comment: The issue may be the path of that. Do a `which laravel-echo-server` and if that gives you a path different than `/var/www/laravel/laravel-echo-server`, you know what the issue is

Comment: Where should I write his command? On the root?

Comment: Yes in the terminal

Comment: Can you please check Update 1?

Comment: You need to add `directory=/var/www/laravel/` also to the config

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two issues. One is the path of the echo server executable and one is the working directory. You need to use below config

```
[program:echo-server]
command=/usr/bin/laravel-echo-server start
dierctory=/var/www/laravel
autostart=true
user=root
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/laravel/storage/logs/echoserver.log
```

This should now help you fix the issues

Comment: any idea about this bounty question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075974/laravel-5-6-passport-driver-not-working-in-socket-io-and-gives-unauthorized-exce