# Laravel 5.6 Passport driver not working in socket.io and gives unauthorized exception

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

Below code was working perfectly when the driver was api. Then I created a new project and changed the driver to passport.

Now, I am always getting Error: Unauthorized. I can confirm that the request header has authorization token code in the browser. **Please check the below image by clicking it and click on zoom to see the image with better quality.**

[image]

Am I missing anything in below code? Please let me know if you need more info.

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
window.Echo = new Echo({
   broadcaster: 'socket.io',
   host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
   auth: {
       headers: {
           Authorization: 'Bearer' + localStorage.getItem("token")
       }
   }
});
```

**Code to post the message using Web socket.io**

```
var config = { 
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
};

var request = {
    "channel": "private-Send-Message-Channel." + message.Sent_To,
    "name": "MessengerEvent",
    "data": {
        "msg": message
    },
    "socket_id": socketId
};
var url = "http://localhost:6001/apps/786d1c1c820025f4/events?auth_key=be1699f0101880f673fdff7ff203334f";

axios.post(url, JSON.stringify(request), this.config).then(response => {
    //success callback
});
```

When the last line of code runs (`axios.post`) , it gives 403, **Unauthorized exception**.

I can confirm that the token is present in the header.

**Update - 1**

I have two sample projects. One with driver = api and another with driver = passport. When I am using driver : api, there is no issue. The above issue is only with driver = passport.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

have you followed the passport documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport ?

In order to get the OAuth authentication, you need more parameters in the body apart from the bearer token.

```
 {
        "grant_type":"password",
        "client_id":"CLIENT_ID",
        "client_secret":"YOUR_SECRET",
        "username":"USERNAME",
        "password":"PASSWORD",
        "scope":""
    }
```